# Docker WordPress configuration not working on localhost with port 8000

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose

I have been working in this `bitnami-wordpress-docker` and still stuck on configuration. I have seen few tutorials in which the command `docker-compose up -d` create bunch of files inside the folder and later localhost:8000 lands to the admin part of the wordpress. But things are not being simple for me.

Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file.

```
version: '3'
services:
  mariadb:
    user: root
    image: 'bitnami/mariadb:10.3'
    volumes:
      - 'mariadb_data:/bitnami'
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MARIADB_USER=bn_wordpress
      - MARIADB_DATABASE=bitnami_wordpress
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    networks:
      - wpsite
  wordpress:
    image: 'bitnami/wordpress:latest'
    ports:
      - '8000:80'
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - 'wordpress_data:/bitnami'
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    environment:
      - MARIADB_HOST=mariadb
      - MARIADB_PORT_NUMBER=3306
      - WORDPRESS_DATABASE_USER=bn_wordpress
      - WORDPRESS_DATABASE_NAME=bitnami_wordpress
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    networks:
      - wpsite
  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: mariadb
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password 
    networks:
      - wpsite
networks:
  wpsite:
volumes:
  mariadb_data:
    driver: local
  wordpress_data:
    driver: local
```

[image: docker ps]

The command I mentioned above is creating containers.
When I try localhost:8000, noting shows. But when localhost:8080 lands me to phpmyadmin page.

Can anybody please tell me how can I setup this Bitnami wordpress using docker. It starts getting frustrating for me.

Thank You.

Comment: Any interesting logs in wordpress container?

Comment: how to check logs? @aMJay

Comment: docker logs -f `container_hash`

Comment: I tried for wordpress container, it gives mysql-c INFO  Trying to connect to MySQL server
Error executing 'postInstallation': Failed to connect to mariadb:3306 after 36 tries

Comment: There is similar issue on github, maybe this can help you https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-testlink/issues/84

Answer (score 1):

Under windows, it often happens to me that some ports are occupied;)
I do that:

1. I start powershell or cmd as admin
2. running `netstat -aon | findstr 8080` the last number is the port
3. I get `TCP 0.0.0.0:8080 0.0.0.0.0 LIETENIN 3428`
4. run `taskkill /f /pid 3428`

And I'm also using the vscode plugin [vscode-docker](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azuretools.vscode-docker) to use for removing all contaners and images.

Take a look at my example of [docker+wordpress+xdebug](https://github.com/tomik23/docker-wordpress-xdebug) maybe something will come in handy ;)